# SQL Server Character replace on large dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace, query-performance

I'm trying to clean up an NVARCHAR(255) column that has several million rows. I want to replace any character that's in my 355 problem character list ( Á -> A ) or remove the character. I've created a table containing the problem characters and the replacement characters.

I've tried several scenarios all in looped batches. The best performance that I've gotten on my local dev box is about 50,000 rows in 1min - 1.5min. I'm hoping to improve on that. There is no index on the new field. First is a CTE that joins on the problem character table.

```
;WITH UctE ( ID, Name, [Count] ) AS (

           SELECT ID, Name, 1 AS [Count]
             FROM dbo.tableName t1
            WHERE t1.ID BETWEEN @StartAtID2 AND @EndAtID2

           UNION ALL

           SELECT UctE.ID, CONVERT( NVARCHAR(255), REPLACE( UctE.Name, cr.ProblemChar, COALESCE(  cr.ReplacementChar, '' ) ) )AS Name, [Count] + 1
             FROM UctE,
                  dbo.CharReplace cr
            WHERE cr.CharReplaceID = [Count]

        ) 
            UPDATE mp
               SET nameversioned = ucte.Name
              FROM dbo.Table1 mp
        INNER JOIN UctE
                ON UctE.Id = mp.ID
               AND ucte.[Count] = 335 
            OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0 );
```

Another version of this uses a replace statement that contains all the problem characters and replacement characters. REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE...to infinity.

```
;WITH UctE ( ID, Name ) AS (

           SELECT ID, (SuperLongReplacestatement)
             FROM dbo.tableName t1
            WHERE t1.ID BETWEEN @StartAtID2 AND @EndAtID2

        ) 
            UPDATE mp
               SET nameversioned = ucte.Name
              FROM dbo.Table1 mp
        INNER JOIN UctE
                ON UctE.Id = mp.ID
            OPTION( MAXRECURSION 0 );
```

I've also tried without the CTE's, but I was hopeful that the batch size would perform better in a CTE. Also, this is my first time posting, so if I've rambled or written this out poorly, please let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't have to *update* large tables. Such replacements should happen while loading the data.

Comment: What percentage of the data needs to change? You could use an INSERT statement to copy all data to a new table and then switch partitions between this and the original table. Partition switching is almost instantaneous. That's a common technique in ETL jobs

Comment: Also, why are these characters considered problematic? They are just characters. Do you have a conversion problem perhaps? Replacing valid characters isn't a good idea. It's better to fix the conversion problem, wherever it is

Comment: Nearly 100% of the rows will be updated. I'm not sure if we can do the partition switch at this time. Right now I've been tasked with figuring out how to update the table in a reasonable time frame. The characters are being removed due to business rules. The conversion problems are being dealt with but old records need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Decompose your queries into more parts.

Process:

1. Find key for every row you would like to update --> find all strings which contain one of your characters you would like to replace.
2. Get Strings for your keys.
3. Remove all chars which you don't want.
4. Join key to key and set your cleansed string into column with messed sting.

If you will update directly (and in one batch) you could lock your table with exclusive locks for long time.

You can try some special collations - for example with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS you can remove ěščřžýáíéúů and many other "unwanted" chars.

Comment: I tried a method where I was joining the tables on the occurrence of problem characters, but the collation cost was going through the roof.

Comment: Yes, you have to separate processes "getwrongdata" and "setcorrecteddata". Try magic with collation or add some examples of wrong data.